# Angular CSS row/col design in ngFor loop

Tags: css, angular6, ngfor

How can align items in row/column depending on condition in ***ngFor**.

If the input type is textarea, then it should be in the next line otherwise on the same line.

[html input from json - **Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typeinformationdynamic)

Comment: can you please specify more clearly, what to do in the attached stackblitz example.

Comment: Use different CSS classes

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is rather simple, you just need to add an extra class in the `div` you are iterating through with `*ngFor` as in:

```
   <div
    *ngFor="let prop of objectProps"
    [ngClass]="{ 'same-line': prop.type !== 'textarea' }"
  >
```

Then you can use that class to set the element's display to inline-block so that it does not go in the next line as in:

```
  .same-line {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
  }
```

(note that I also needed to specify the width as that needs to be known here)

This is the result:

[image]

And I you can also see this working in the following fork of your stackblitz demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typeinformationdynamic-i24na7?file=app/dynamic-form.component.ts

Comment: lol I was trying to answer an old question in order to get the Revival badge... but this is 2 years old lol... (I just noticed it)